# Team City - No Compatible Agents Found

Tags: .net, msbuild, teamcity

Folks,

I am trying to use Team City. I completed the six steps out of 7. Now for the last step, under the tab "`Agent Requirements`", it is showing me the following message

> Agents compatibility
>   In this section you can see which agents are
>   compatible with requirements and which are not.
>
> **There are no agents registered.**

Why it is showing this message ? Any solution ?

or rather, how to register an agent ?

---

**EDIT :** I already installed the Agent via MS Windows Installer, but it still shows me the same above message

**Screenshot :**

[image]

**Finally managed to get this output :)**

[image]

Comment: Your team city thinks you have no agents, period. What is shown in the "Agents" page (the link all the way up at the top).

Comment: yeah .. it shows "no agents available".. But then i tried installing agent via MS Windows Installer, but it still shows me the same message .. Do I need to re-login to check that ?

Comment: I have the similiar issue, cant see a new agent even after I install one. How did you resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your agents tab title says - `Agents (0)` - that means you have no registered agents. Go to the Agents tab and see if the agent(s) that you want are authorized and connected. ( the first time an agent connects to the server, it has to be authorized from the Agents page - checkout http://server/agents.html?tab=unauthorizedAgents)

Comment: @herbalessence - Added link. Go there and click on the unauthorized and authorize it

Comment: @herbalessence - What some different page?

Comment: it is showing me this message `There  are no unauthorized agents found. Agent licenses left: 3. `

Comment: @herbalessence - See around that page. There are many tabs like "Disconnected", "Connected" etc. Find your agent. Post a screenshot of that page if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I finally managed to get the solution and eventually, "Success" message. .. I installed a `Java  Web Start` and was then able to see `1 agent connected option` ..

Comment: Is there any good tutorial on learning team city and this overall process ?

Comment: @herbalessence - their docs are a good place. http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/documentation/index.jsp

Comment: see the success screen shot .. is this what to expect in the end ?

Comment: @herbalessence - Yeah, look fine. See the build log and see it has done what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 2):

One reason may be that the Build Agent itself is either 1. not running (build agent service is not actually running - check the status of the service via the windows 'local services' admin panel), 2. not able to connect to the Team City server.

In either case, I found reading the build agent's logs to be very helpful in identifying the underlying issues.  These can be found in the build_agent_install_dir/logs folder.

Comment: In my case, the problem was I give to the build agent a wrong port number of the build server. However, looking at the log files helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had an similar issue. Created a new project and had two agents which should be compatible. But project showed no compatible agents and ALSO no incompatible agents!

In my case i had to manually add my new project to the default Agents Pool. Go to `Agents > Pools`, and click the button `Assign agents..`